# Использование filter Stream api

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream, filter

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получиться отсортированный по фамилии список потенциально работоспособных людей с высшим образованием в выборке (т.е. людей с высшим образованием от 18 до 60 лет для женщин и до 65 лет для мужчин).
С сортировкой проблем нет. Не понятно как с помощью метода .filter() отфильтровать мужчин по определенному возрасту и женщин по определенному возрасту. По логике напрашивается тернарный оператор, на как его использовать вместе с .filter() не понятно

```
    persons.stream()
            .filter(age -> age.getAge() > 18)
             *//как отфильтровать по возрасту в заисимости о пола*
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFamily))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Сам список

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Jack", "Connor", "Harry", "George", "Samuel", "John");
    List<String> families = Arrays.asList("Evans", "Young", "Harris", "Wilson", "Davies", "Adamson", "Brown");
    Collection<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
        persons.add(new Person(
                names.get(new Random().nextInt(names.size())),
                families.get(new Random().nextInt(families.size())),
                new Random().nextInt(100),
                Sex.Sex1.values()[new Random().nextInt(Sex.Sex1.values().length)],
                Education.Education1.values()[new Random().nextInt(Education.Education1.values().length)]).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны несколько вариантов решения:

- объединение несколько условий при помощи логического ИЛИ `||`:

```java
enum Sex {MALE, FEMALE;}
// ...

persons.stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getAge() >= 18) // minAge
    .filter(person -> (Sex.MALE == person.getSex() && person.getAge() <= 65)
        || (Sex.FEMALE == person.getSex() && person.getAge() <= 60)
    )
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFamily))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

- Использование тернарного оператора:

```java
persons.stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getAge() >= 18
        && person.getAge() <= (Sex.MALE == person.getSex() ? 65 : 60)
    )
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFamily))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

- Добавление параметра `maxAge` в `enum Sex`:

```java
enum Sex { 
    MALE(65), FEMALE(60);

    private final int maxAge;

    private Sex(int maxAge) { this.maxAge = maxAge; }

    public int getMaxAge() { return this.maxAge(); }
}
```

Тогда фильтрация может быть переписана так

```java
persons.stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getAge() >= 18 
        && person.getAge() <= person.getSex().getMaxAge()
    )
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getFamily))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

- Реализация соответствующей логики в классе `Person` или соответствующем утилитном методе (c учётом предыдущего пункта):

```java
public class Person {
    // ...
    public boolean hasValidAge() {
        return getAge() >= 18 && getAge() <= getSex().getMaxAge();
    }
}

persons.stream()
    .filter(Person::hasValidAge)
    // ...
```

Или так:

```java
public class Util {
    private Util() {}

    public static boolean hasValidAge(@NonNull Person person) {
        return person.getAge() >= 18 && person.getAge() <= getSex().getMaxAge();
    }
// ...
}

// ...
persons.stream()
    .filter(Util::hasValidAge)
```